# What Triggers the Firebase DISCONNECTED and NETWORK_ERROR DatabaseErrors?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an Android application that uses the Firebase RealTime Database and Firebase Cloud functions. Several of my cloud functions are triggered by writes to the RealTime database and are used further process data saved by the Android client application.

I'd like my app to handle network connectivity changes gracefully. I understand that Firebase handles loss of connection by saving changes to the RealTime database locally and then syncing the changes to the server when connectivity is restored. This is [well documented in the Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence).

In my case though, since I need the Cloud Function post-processing of data saved to some paths to have occurred before it is useful, there's no point in having this data saved if it isn't going to make it to the server (and therefore trigger a Cloud Function), in a timely manner.

I'm using the `updateChildren` function from [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) to save the data and have a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) attached to monitor the outcome. I thought I may be able to use the `DISCONNECTED` and/or `NETWORK_ERROR` [DatabaseError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseError)s to identify cases where my data won't be reaching the server. However, if I interrupt the network connection before `updateChildren` is called, there aren't any errors generated. In this case, Firebase has likely saved the data locally with plans to sync it later, so `updateChildren` is considered to have been completed successfully.

My questions then are:

1. When are the `DatabaseErrors` `DISCONNECTED` and `NETWORK_ERROR` actually used by Firebase? Can I use them in some way to help manage connectivity issues?
2. What are the best practices for handling cases where Firebase data must make it to the server in order to be useful? Should I really just be POSTing my data to the Cloud Function directly?
3. Does Firebase have any notion of a timeout period that can be watched and data invalidated if it isn't synced within a specific period of time?

Yes, I recognize that I can use a listener attached to [`/.info/connected`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) to detect changes in the connection state, but I'd rather be able to react and gracefully handle my case as it happens. I feel that my usage of the Realtime database together with Cloud Functions is common enough that there must be generally accepted way to implement it.

Any thoughts appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Did you use [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect](OnDisconnect) method and Interface ?

Comment: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.OnDisconnect](OnDisconnect)